# Rails params not pulling in the right value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pull in the ids of a select statement in my controller. I know that I use the params to do this but the params seem not to work on the select statements.

controller

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.employer_id = current_employer.id
@post.store_id = params[:store_id]
@post.category_id = params[:category_id]
if @post.save
  redirect_to stores_path
else

end
```

end

view

```
 <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <%= f.select :store_id, @stores.all.map{|u| [u.name, u.id]},{}, {class: 'form-control selectpicker'} %>
        <%= link_to 'Add new Store', new_store_path, class: 'help-block' %>
      </div>
```

Everything seems right to my but this is the first time a used select tag in rails.

Comment: can you paste your params?

Comment: "store_id"=>"1", "about"=>"", @DivyangHirpara

Comment: please copy the whole response from console and paste it here

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2Yr44rAFMnUjv6BUUCFF9dfeeY24Gl1cLiCf0gMXB5btY3NSJAugqbBRUVpJY1by7lBiYROZg==",
 "job_post"=>{"title"=>"test 13", "store_id"=>"1", "about"=>"", "job_type"=>"Full Time", "salary"=>"", "hours"=>"", "category_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"} @DivyangHirpara

Answer (score 1):

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.employer_id = current_employer.id
@post.store_id = params[:job_post][:store_id]
@post.category_id = params[:job_post][:category_id]
if @post.save
  redirect_to stores_path
else

end
```

It will work and pull right value.
You store_id, category_id are in job_post so it will not access direct params[:store_id]. It's for more detail please read rails [strong parameter](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)